# Arduino управление GSM модулем через WEB server

Tags: веб-программирование, arduino

Помогите с решением задачи,
мне надо отправлять AT команды на GSM module sim800L через WEB сервер поднятый на той же Arduino. Можно ли вопрос решить с 1 Arduino MEGA, или нужно две платы, или это вообще не реально? Спасибо

Comment: Всё реально, ну, почти всё. Другое дело, что совсем непонятна постановка задачи. Какие трудности?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, только нужен будет либо Wi-Fi модуль, либо модуль подключения к LAN - ENC28j60 ( или подобные)

Можно обойтис например так: ESP8266 + GSM module